# Retrieve argument type of function operator of an object

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, c++03

I have a wrapper which transforms functions taking several arguments into functions taking just a single argument (values for the other arguments are provided). This code works with *functions*:

```
template <class R, class F, class A0, class A1>
class CMyWrapper {
     F m_f;
     A0 m_default_a0;

public:
     CMyWrapper(F f, const A0 &default_a0)
         :m_f(f), m_default_a0(default_a0)
     {}

     R operator ()(const A1 &a1) const
     {
         return m_f(m_default_a0, a1);
     }
};

template <class R, class A0, class A1>
CMyWrapper<R, R (*)(const A0&, const A1&), A0, A1>
    SupplyConstArg(R (*fun)(const A0&, const A1&), const A0 &default_a0)
{
    return CMyWrapper<R, R (*)(const A0&, const A1&), A0, A1>(fun, default_a0);
}

double MyFunc(const double &x, const double &y); // some function
```

so now I can do e.g. `SupplyConstArg(MyFunc, 1.23)(4.56)` which calls `MyFunc(1.23, 4.56)` (the left part of this expression is a function object which supplies a constant first argument). So far so good.

However, I have some difficulties in writing a similar function working for *function objects* rather than functions (I'd like to avoid function pointers for performance reasons where possible). Assuming:

```
struct CMyFunObj {
    double operator ()(const double &x, const double &y);
};
```

my problem is **how do I match the return type or the types of the arguments, given an instance of such function object**? So far, I came up with:

```
template <class F, class R, class A0, class A1>
R Infer(F f, R (F::*fun)(const A0 &a0, const A1 &a1) = &F::operator ());
```

which sort of works, but only if the second argument is also specified, e.g. by calling:

```
Infer(CMyFunObj(), &CMyFunObj::operator ());
```

but not if I omit the second argument and rely on the default value. Any ideas how to do it in C++03?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to re-implement a portion of std::bind. In C++03 this portion is provided by std::bind1st.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, I'm aware that this is similar. In my use case, the constant argument is not always the first, I need some functionality to specify the index of the "variable argument" which will be specified in the function operator of the returned function object. I'm able to do this part already, I'm just stuck with the type inference for function objects. Not sure one could do the same for `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++03, you can't really infer the type like that (unless you want to use like `typeof`), so you have to actually provide it:

```
struct CMyFunObj {
    typedef double result_type;
    double operator()(const double &x, const double &y);
};
```

And now you can use that additional bit of information:

```
template <class F, class A0>
CMyWrapper<typename F::result_type, F, A0>
SupplyConstArg(F f, A0 const& a0) {
    return CMyWrapper<typename F::result_type, F, A0>(f, a0);
}

SupplyConstArg(CMyFunObj(), 4.0)(5.0);
```

You don't need the type `A1` in `CMyWrapper`, that can be a template argument on its `operator()`.

Comment: Eh, after a bit of trudging with `typeof`, I get `sorry, unimplemented: mangling typeof, use decltype instead`. Seems like it indeed can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got the question, but probably you mean something like this?

```
struct X {};
struct Y {};

template <class R, class A0, class A1, class F, R(F::*)(const A0 &, const A1 &) = &F::operator()>
void Infer(F f) { }

struct S {
    void operator()(const X &, const Y &) { }
    void foo(const X &, const Y &) { }
};

int main() {
    Infer<void, X, Y>(S{});
    Infer<void, X, Y, S, &S::foo>(S{});
}
```

As from the comments, this should work in C++03:

```
struct X {};
struct Y {};

template <class R, class A0, class A1, class F>
void Infer(F f, R(F::*ptr)(const A0 &, const A1 &)) { (f.*ptr)(A0(), A1()); }

template<class F>
void Infer(F f) {
    Infer(f, &F::operator());
}

struct S {
    void operator()(const X &, const Y &) { }
    void foo(const int &, const char &) { }
};

int main() {
    Infer(S());
    Infer(S(), &S::foo);
}
```

This way, you can either specify the method to be called or rely on an intermediate function that explicitly pushes it as an argument.

Comment: Ooopsy I wanted to do it exactly the same like but it apparently needs c++11

Comment: This works but it seems difficult to use. I'd like `Infer` to infer the types automatically, rather than by the caller having to write them out.

Comment: @theswine are you sure you need c++03 approach?

Comment: I have a huge project which is in C++03, I'm not going to migrate everything to C++11 because of this feature which is relatively minor in the scope of the project. I'm not sure why wouldn't your approach work in C++03 though, just drop the curly brackets in the second and third last lines of the code and replace them by round ones. Is there something else?

Comment: I'm not sure it adds anything new though.

Comment: @theswine Just modified, I suspect the easiest way to have it working with C++03 is by using an intermediate function and that's all.

Comment: @skypjack The problem now is that the inner function knows the types. But how do you get them out?

Comment: @theswine By calling directly the outer function if the default method is not the one you want to use. I don't get the problem, it looks like you want to provide a default choice, but also you don't want to provide it. I guess I missed something from your question and I apologize for this.

Comment: @skypjack No need to appologise :). What I want out is a function object which I can pass to e.g. `std::transform` or whatever, as in the case of `CMyWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an intermediate function:

```
template <class F, class R, class A0, class A1>
void Infer(F f, R (F::*fun)(const A0 &a0, const A1 &a1));

template <class F>
void Infer(F f) {
    Infer(f, &F::operator());
}

Infer(CMyFunObj());
```

If you need to infer the type, you can do [as Barry says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616486/2666289), and if you do not want to modify your functors, you can use an external helper class:

```
template <class U>
struct result_type;

template <typename F>
typename result_type<F>::type Infer(F f) {
    return Infer(f, &F::operator());
}
```

And then later:

```
struct CMyFunObj {
    double operator ()(const double& x, const double& y) { return x + y; }
};

template <>
struct result_type<CMyFunObj> {
    typedef double type;
};
```

Comment: Right, I see I oversimplified the example. Assuming that `Infer` would need to return the same type as `F::operator ()`, how would I get that to the outer function? It is easz to get it in the inner.

Comment: @theswine I don't know if there is a way to do what you want (according to Barry there is not). I updated my answer providing a way to do like Barry but without modifying the functors.